# Display Last Child in React Iteration

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement a message app, without ActionCable for now. When I map over all messages, I want to show only the last message from that user: instead of showing all messages, from a user, I only show the last. I do not know how to achieve that. I thought I could set the `key` to the `user_id` instead of the `id`.

```
_messagesRender: function(){
  var messages = this.props.message.map( function(m, i){
    return(
      <li key={m.user_id}>{m.body}</li>
    )
  });
  return(
    <div>{messages.length === 0 ? "No messages" : messages}</div>
  )
},
```

This component is on the index page and I'm trying to create a message-like app. Any pointers with React? Rails 5 is used as back end.

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.$2`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

**Back end:**

```
@messages = Message.where(to: current_user.id)
```

Message model: `:id, :to, :user_id, :body`

`user_id` is who sends/created the message.

Comment: @potashin Sorry. Post is updated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, by the way?(MySQL, Postgres, etc)

Comment: Im using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Message.where(to: current_user.id)
       .order(:created_at)
       .group_by(&:user_id)
       .map{|_, x| x.last}
```

This should give the last message (by `created_at`) from each `user_id`.

As long as you are using Postgresql, you can try `distinct on` approach:

```
Message.where(to: current_user.id)
       .order(user_id: :asc, created_at: :desc)
       .select('distinct on (user_id) *')
```

Comment: Great! Since the `user_id` is the user that creates the message, I could safely replace `:from` with `:user_id`?

Comment: @Sylar: Yes, you can

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Sylar: I can't test the second approach though as I don't have Posgres installed on my machine)

Comment: The first works great. I'll test the second later then let you know.

Comment: @Sylar: The first solution fetches all records from DB and then is filtered on the application side leaving only first message for each user, while the second solution does the filtering part on the DB side

Comment: I was just about to ask about the performance of the first. Ok, I'll confirm later.

Comment: You have a tiny error: `desc` should be `:desc`. Last one also works. Nice.

Comment: Sorry for the pain, is it possible to modify the code to show the last message between both users? A new question for this? When I reply, its not showing on the index. It only shows on the `show` page.

Comment: @Sylar: The approach should be different, I think it is better to post another question, if you want, you can link it here, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yes it's different. Ill you know once. Thanks

Comment: Ok, message posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879169/show-last-message-in-a-message-array