# Show last message in a message array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Regarding [my last attempted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862226/display-last-child-in-react-iteration/37862330), I could achieve what I wanted. Once the app is working I noticed something is different: only the person that created the message and sends a message was only showing. If I reply, I do not see the reply and I know the problem.

My **Message** model has tables: `[:id, :user_id, :to, :body, ...]`

`:user_id` would be similar to `from` as that is used to determine who created the message.

`User 1` would be Client and `User 2` is Student. Student sends a message to Client. Only my client side the code is as this:

```
#Controller Index:

@messages = Message.where(to: current_user.id) # My replies are not included here
       .order(user_id: :asc, created_at: :desc)
       .select('distinct on (user_id) *')
```

I'm saying give me all messages that's addressed to me (`:to`) an id of `1`.

I won't see my reply because of the `:to` column.

**My (client) reply looks like this:**

```
to: #student id
user_id: #client id
```

**And student message:**

```
to: #client id
user_id: #student id
```

So because the `to` now point to an id, let's say `2` I wont see the reply. I may need to change up the model but if you see an easy way, please let me know.

Edit:

Answer that works great:

```
@messages = Message.where(to: current_user.id).or(Message.where(user_id: current_user.id))
                 .order(connection: :desc, created_at: :desc)
                 .select('distinct on (connection) *')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Rails 5, you can take advantage of it's `or` method:

```rb
Message.where(to: current_user.id).or(
 Message.where(user_id: current_user.id)
).order(connection: :desc, created_at: :desc)
 .select('distinct on (connection) *')
```

Comment: getting `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end , expecting ')'`

Comment: Yes, your code give me last reply, in console, but breaks the code in my post which is the answer in the link.

Comment: I've added the `.or()` to my existing code and that's it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sylar: for the message or for the conversation?

Comment: @Sylar: Cause if it is for the message, you should get in the result set both last received and sent messages.

Comment: Not for the conversation, just the index page where you see all messages addressed to you.

Comment: @Sylar: it probably doesn't work correctly though (if I've understood your question correctly), assuming that connection is unique for each posted message.

Comment: No connection is unique id for the array of messages between both client and student. So message.last and message.first etc will have the same connection id.  If a different user creates a message then the connection id is different.

Comment: @Sylar: Yeah,  by this I meant conversation)))

Comment: Code works. So cant complain. Thanks again. Oh, works both on client and student side ;)